# hHow to use maximum principle of $\frac{1}{f}$ in points where $f(x) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Suppose That I am trying to use the maximum principle on $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ in order to use the minimum principle over $f(x)$.
How do I deal with points in which $f(x) = 0$?

I didn't encounter a question like that, I am just wondering.

Thanks!

Comment: You **don't**! If there are points where f(x)= 0 then 1/f(x) does **not** have a maximum.

Comment: This question is answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292067/dont-understand-proof-of-minimum-modulus-principle